# How to loop with condition

Tags: php

This is my $update array

```
Array
(
[0] => 08:31:08
[1] => 08:32:08
[2] => 08:33:08
[3] => 10:34:08
[4] => 08:51:08
[5] => 08:21:08
[6] => 10:39:08
[7] => 08:41:08
[8] => 08:49:08
[9] => 08:20:08
[10] => 08:11:08
[11] => 10:50:08
)
```

This is my code

```
$default_computed = 9:30:00
$timin ="";

  for ($x=0; $x < count($update) ; $x++) { 

      if (strtotime($update[$x]) > strtotime($default_computed) ) {

            $timin .= $update[$x].',';
            $replace_timin = substr_replace($timin ,"",-1);
            $updated_timin = explode(",",$replace_timin);
            $late_time_in = count($updated_timin);

            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($update);
            print_r($timin);
            die();
  }
}
```

i want this output but its stop already for 1 time

```
10:34:08,10:39:08,10:50:08,
```

how can i loop continuously to get my target output?

Comment: I don't think you need the `die` method, since that terminates your script

Comment: replace die() with break;

Comment: i move the die() at the end of the loop its complete already thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your script is trying to figure out which time inside the array is beyond the cutoff time (which is `$default_computed = 9:30:00`).

With this in mind, I'd suggest you take on a different approach on this problem and avoid string manipulations (using `substr_replace`, `explode` and such) and start using `DateTime` classes instead:

```
$default_computed = '9:30:00'; // cutoff time
$cutoff = new DateTime($default_computed); // using DateTime
foreach ($update as $time) { // so each time element inside the array
    $time_in = new DateTime($time); // load each time
    if ($time_in >= $cutoff) { // if this time is beyond the cutoff
        echo $time_in->format('H:i:s'); // output it
    }
}
```

They're much easier and straightforward to use since you just load in the time and you can compare `DateTime` to `DateTime` objects directly in the `if` conditions.

So its basically each `time in` inside the array compared to the `cutoff` time.

Answer (score 0):

```
$update =  array
    (
    '08:31:08',
    '08:32:08',
    '08:33:08',
    '10:34:08',
    '08:51:08',
    '08:21:08',
    '10:39:08',
    '08:41:08',
    '08:49:08',
    '10:50:08'
    );

$default_computed = '9:30:00'; 
$default_computed= date("H:i:s", strtotime($default_computed)); // Convert your string to time


for($i=0; $i < count($update) ; $i++){

    $update[$i]= date("H:i:s", strtotime($update[$i])); //Convert each elements of the array into time format
    if($update[$i]>$default_computed)
    echo $update[$i].",";

}
```